# Сложная запись в файл

Tags: файлы, php

Есть сайт с посещаемостью 100 000 уников в сутки и при каждом посещении будет исполняться такой вот код для записи данных в файл:

```
<?php
    $fp = fopen("fi/qwe.txt", "a"); 
    $mytext = "Эту строку необходимо записать\r\n"; 
    $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); 
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Могу ли я быть уверен, что если два человека одновременно зайдут на сайт, то не возникнет ошибки при записи в файл? просьба ответить те, кто действительно уверен ответе, для меня это очень важно. спасибо!

Comment: Вы открываете файл в режиме добавления, SO говорит, что все тип-топ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4755722  
Но в целом ниже правильную вещь посоветовали - если есть многопоточное обращение к файлу, то лучше его реализовать в виде базы данных.

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/146959/php-file_put_contents-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82) задавал полтора года назад тут : )

Answer (score 1):

Смотря какая платформа и какая файловая система. Лучше монгу рядом поставить и плевать туда.

Comment: подскажите, что за монга такая? первый раз сышу

Comment: mongoDB, а то с файлом может быть много непредвиденных ситуаций.

Comment: не обязательно mongo. Любая СУБД имеет средства для решения подобных задач

Comment: Да согласен, можно )

Answer (score 1):

[Почитай: flock](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.flock.php)

А так да, лучше базу использовать. Не понимаю смысла использования файлов.

Answer (score 1):

С приведенным кодом нет, не можете. Пользуйтесь блокировками

```
$fp = fopen ("fi/qwe.txt","a");
flock ($fp, LOCK_EX);
fputs($fp ,"Эту строку необходимо записать\r\n");
fflush ($fp);
flock ($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose ($fp);
```

но имейте ввиду, что это дополнительные задержки на открытие страницы. Запись в файл - не самый лучший вариант при высоких нагрузках.

Comment: ДА, может хорошенько тормозить при больших очередях на запись в файл.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то тебе ерунду тут насоветовали. Вот код в одну строчку, который будет работать так, как тебе надо)

```
file_put_contents("fi/qwe.txt", "Эту строку необходимо записать\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: А блокировать файл на время записи кто будет?  
Тогда уж так:  

    file_put_contents("fi/qwe.txt", "Эту строку необходимо записать\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: @Денис Евра, спешу вас поздравить с тем, что ваш код абсолютно идентичен приведенному автором. Ерунду ему, блин, насоветовали.

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

Ещё не было «Плана-Б» с логами веб сервера: что Apache, что nginx прекрасно умеют писать в лог-файлы всё что нужно про каждый индивидуальный визит, несмотря на кажущуюся одновременность.

Если строка не формируется сложными вычислениями в php скрипте, то может, писать в отдельный лог самим веб-сервером?

Comment: на самом деле все проще - если строка влезает в буфер, то перекрытия не будет, вот формальная демонстрация:

    $ cat a.php
    <?php
    file_put_contents("test.txt","Begin:".rand(0,10000).":END\n",FILE_APPEND);
    $ for ((a=0;a<1000;a++));do php a.php & done
    ...
    [1000]+  Done                    php a.php
    $ egrep -v  '^Begin:[0-9]+:END' test.txt ;wc -l test.txt 
    1000 test.txt